# Fibonacci Sequence Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a quick question about another Visual Basic assignment I'm working on. I have all the code and everything has gone smoothly so far. The app is meant to display the first 100 Fibonacci numbers in a list box, adding the two previously displayed numbers to get the next in a loop. The only problem is that when I hit the button to display the code, the loop continues, and doesn't just stop at 100 numbers. Where did I go wrong?

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Dim dblA As Double = 0
    Dim dblB As Double = 1
    Dim dblC As Double
    Dim intCounter As Integer

    lstSequence.Items.Add(dblA.ToString)
    lstSequence.Items.Add(dblB.ToString)

    For intCounter = 1 To 100
        dblC = dblA + dblB
        dblA = dblB
        dblB = dblC
        lstSequence.Items.Add(dblC.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Debug your code.  You don't work out what is wrong with code simply by reading it.  That is a first step but, if the issue isn't obvious, the next step is to execute the code and watch it in action, i.e. debug it. If you don't know how to debug properly, i.e. using breakpoints, stepping through the code an examining state using tool windows like Autos, Watch and Immediate, then now is the time to learn.  Debugging is an essential tool for a developer.  Without it, you're just a code-writer.

Comment: By the way, why are you using type `Double`? You're only using whole numbers and Fibonacci Numbers are specifically whole numbers so why would you choose `Double` to represent them?

Comment: Yes, it does. See [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I just ran you code and nothing is wrong. It works. I would suggest debugging this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this.  It works fine.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim a As Integer = 0
        Dim b As Integer = 1
        Dim fib As Integer
        Dim userinput, i As Integer
        userinput = InputBox("how many interations?")
        i = userinput
        ListView1.Items.Add(1)
        Do
            fib = a + b
            a = b
            b = fib
            ListView1.Items.Add(fib)
            i = i + 1
        Loop While fib < i

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

[image]